# Rewrite Rule Config... Is this possible?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

So I have a set of pages like so:

```
domain.com/product/?_d=1
domain.com/product/?_d=2
domain.com/product/?_d=3
```

I have set up a rewrite map for cleaner URLs like so

```
domain.com/shoes
domain.com/pants
domain.com/gloves
```

So now I have nice URLs for people. But what I also want to do is start forwarding the existing URLs to the newer URLs. So for anyone who goes to:

```
domain.com/product/?_d=1
```

I want them to be forwarded or rewrite the URL to:

```
domain.com/shoes
```

I tried adding in another map where I have the following:

```
Original: domain.com/product/?_d=1
New Value: domain.com/shoes
```

And I got a 404. I guess I understand why because the other map won't apply since I am using the first map. But how can I set up a map for the old URLs? Or can I? I know if my query string value was like _d=shoes I could just do a rewrite rule, but it's not like that. I guess I could change my page to be that way, but was just looking for another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a rewrite rule that looked for the pattern to the old URLs and forwarded them to the new URL. Then in my Server side code I just did a check for those legacy variables and redirected with a 301 accordingly.